# Automatic discount coupon if purchase over 100 dollars

Tags: extensions, promotions, coupon

Is there a way to offer customer automatically a discount coupon if order is over 100 dollars? Better yet if the discount coupon could be emailed to customer with the order confirmation email.

Maybe there is some extension somewhere well hidden...?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create your module like this

1) Create your custom module basic steps like module configuration file and all.

2) Create the observer for the check your amount is grater than 100$ or not.

3) The observer event is sales_order_place_after and sales_order_place_before.

4) If you want to give discount coupon on current order is grater then 100$ then you can use  **sales_order_place_before** event if not then you can use **sales_order_place_after**.

5) hope you know the how to create the observer.

6) For you email sending you have to create the custom email template and in observer method you have to send mail via Mail template using Zend library.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this through observers and layout updates. You can create an Observer that listens some event that is triggered after an order is placed in the checkout. In this Observer, you should check if the order is over 100 dollars. If yes, create and send the discount coupon in the confirmation e-mail.
Maybe you can get some ideas how to do this using the following module; you have to make your discount coupon a gift:
http://www.code4business.de/make-a-gift-magento-warenkorbpreisregeln-um-geschenke-erweitern/